# SSIS - Inability to build a query for a DataFlow source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I have a couple of problems converting Stored Procedures to queries that work in SSIS packages.

One of them is an `INSERT INTO .. SELECT <query with subquery>` that has the following caracteristics that SSIS and data providers does not like:

- It has parameters in subquery and in the `SELECT` list, specifically it's the reference day for the data. If I import data of yesterday, it would be the date of yesterday. I need it to filter and do not import the whole database everytime.
- Since the parameter is inside a subquery, is seems to not being recognized by OLE DB, or at least many people say that and it seems to be like that.
- For a strange reason, even formatting the query as expression and use it with ADO.NET provider (SqlClient) it gives me evaluation error everytime.
- I cannot create a view of the query since the parameter (which I can transform in `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))` is non-deterministic.

How can I solve this? How can I format/transform/edit this query to let it work inside a DataFlow Source? Note that since we are converting projects, we can actually change data providers, so if a provider has better support for this kind of problems, please tell me.

I can provide the full query if asked to.

Comment: Just before query set parameters. `declare @yesterday date; set @yesterday = 'your parameter(variable) in SSIS package' ` and in subquery use @yesterday...

Comment: Justin one of my problem was the inability to map parameters in everyway. OLE DB just throw me an error if I put a ? in the subquery. With ADO.NET I need a Script Task + Dummy query for metadata

Comment: I think `?` parameter in subquery don't work, first just try simple query (without subquery) and then say if works...

Comment: Oh yeah it works with simple queries. It just does not work with mine. The issue is the combination of all the problems I described.

Comment: I just gave up, and rolled back all the changes. All the effort is not worth the small performance increase.

Comment: Hi not sure if this will help. Can you call the stored proc from the data flow task by executing the stored proc, and passing the parameter.  If you include 'SET FMTONLY OFF' before calling the stored proc, you will not get the error msg about no column info

SET FMTONLY OFF
EXEC dbo.[Name of Stored Proc] ?

Comment: So i can return the whole dataset from a stored procedure? That would be so good since we already have [bad] stored procedures that use linked servers for the ETL process. We could just edit those ones. I'll try.